# Can a function generated using JavaScript's eval be optimised?

Tags: javascript

We all know that using `eval()` is frought with danger and should really never be used. But let's imagine that you have complete control over the input to eval and it can be used safely.

My question is, if I were to generate a function using `eval()` like below and then call the generated function many times, would this benefit from compiler/runtime optimizations in browser runtimes such as say, V8?

```
eval('var myFunction = function() { return 1 * 2 / 3 }')
myFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest that it has a negative impact on runtime since the function is parsed when `eval()` is called, not when the document is loaded.

Optimizations by the Javascript Engine (like V8) are not influenced by the way a function is generated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I understand. Generating the function will be slower with eval because compilation is delayed, but if the function is stored somewhere and used later it can be optimised like any other function

Comment: @ChrisBellew You can edit your own comment. Please don't add another just to fix a typo.